# How to set a NavLink to active conditionally on dynamic links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my menu, I have a navigation link- **My Profile**. When the user clicks **My Profile** react redirects to their profile. Then the nav link is set to active as expected, likewise, the `isActive` style is applied.

```js
        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/my_profile" activeStyle={isActive}>
          My Profile
        </NavLink>
```

A user can navigate to users' profiles by navigating to [www.sitename.com/***username**](http://www.sitename.com/***username**)* (like Twitter or Instagram).

```js
          <Route path="/:profile_name">
            <Profile />
          </Route>
```

When a user is logged in and navigates to *their own* profile through this dynamic route, I want the nav link for **My Profile** to be set to active. But I can only figure out how to set **My Profile** to active when **My Profile** is clicked on, not when the user navigates to their own profile through the address bar.

How can I set the `NavLink` for **My Profile** to active when a user navigates to their dynamic profile route through the address bar?

#### Example

In my code example, I have the `currentUser` hard coded in as `dash123`, so when we navigate to  `http://somedomain.com/dash123` the `Profile` component recognizes `/dash123` is the current user's profile and sets the state `authorized` to true. When authorized is `true`, `Profile` renders to display "Edit your profile". Can I also make it so when `authorized` is `true`, the `NavLink` for **My Profile** is set to active?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/active-nav-link-not-working-65igb?file=/src/App.js:0-2794)

Code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  NavLink,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

function Nav() {
  const isActive = {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey"
  };

  return (
    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/Shop" activeStyle={isActive}>
          Shop
        </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/my_profile" activeStyle={isActive}>
          My Profile
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}
function Shop(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      Lots of items to buy
      <br /> Shoes $4.99
      <br /> Carrots $9.99
      <br /> Teslas $800,000
    </div>
  );
}
function Profile(props) {
  let { profile_name } = useParams();
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState();
  const [authorized, setAuthorized] = useState(null);

  // fake calls to database
  const currentUser = () => {
    return { name: "Dashie" };
  };
  const userInfo = (username) => {
    const db = [
      { username: "dash123", name: "Dashie" },
      { username: "bob123", name: "Bob" }
    ];
    return db.find((userDoc) => userDoc.username === username);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.profile === "currentUser") {
      setProfile(currentUser());
    } else {
      setProfile(userInfo(profile_name));
    }
  }, [profile_name, props.profile]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (profile && profile.name === currentUser().name) {
      setAuthorized(true);
    }
  }, [profile]);

  return (
    <div>
      Profile:
      <br />
      {profile && <>Name: {profile.name}</>}
      <br />
      {authorized && profile && <>Edit your profile, {profile.name}</>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/shop">
            <Shop />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/my_profile">
            <Profile profile={"currentUser"} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/:profile_name">
            <Profile />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <h2>Problem</h2>
      <p>
        If you click on <b>Shop</b>, as expected the <b>Shop</b> nav link will
        be highlighted.
        <br />
        <br /> Likewise, the <b>My Profile</b> nav link will be highlighted when
        we click on it and navigate to the user's profile.
        <br />
        <br /> But, we also want to have <b>My Profile</b> highlighted when we
        navigate to,{" "}
        <i>
          "https://whateverdomainyouron/<b>dash123</b>"
        </i>{" "}
        since this takes us to the current user's profile.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took Drew Reese's suggestions and expanded on them to fit my needs.

I made it so the My Profile link is active if `isProfileRoute` and `currentUsersProfile` is met.

```js
        <NavLink
          isActive={() => isProfileRoute && currentUsersProfile}
          className="nav-link"
          to="/my_profile"
          activeStyle={isActive}
        >
```

`currentUsersProfile` is on the AuthContext.

```
const AuthContext = createContext({
  authorized: false,
  profile: null,
  currentUsersProfile: null,
  setAuthorized: () => {},
  setProfile: () => {},
  setCurrentUsersProfile: () => {},
});
```

The `currentUsersProfile` is set in `Profile` to true when the current profile belongs to the current logged in user.:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (profile?.name === currentUser().name) {
      setAuthorized(true);
      setCurrentUsersProfile(true);
    } else {
      setCurrentUsersProfile(false);
    }
  }, [profile]);
```

I create an array of all the routes:

```js
const Routes = (
    <Switch>
    <Route path="/shop">
      <Shop />
    </Route>
    <Route path={"/pro"}>
      <Profile />
    </Route>
    <Route path={["/:profile_name", "/my_profile"]}>
      <Profile />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);
const array = Routes.props.children.map((child) => child.props.path);
// outputs: ['/shop', '/pro', ["/:profile_name", "/my_profile"]]
```

In `Nav` I use this array to check to see if the current route the user is on is a the profile route (ex: '/dash123', '/somename', or the fixed route '/my_profile') using `useMatchRoute`

```js
function Nav() {
  const { currentUsersProfile } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const allNonProfileRoutes = array.slice(0, -1);
  let nonProfileRoute = useRouteMatch([...allNonProfileRoutes, { path: "/" }]);

  const isProfileRoute = !nonProfileRoute.isExact;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/active-nave-link-6-x0uyq?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 4):

## Issue

Your auth state resides in your `Profile` component so it isn't reachable within the `Nav` component.

## Solution

Refactor your code to lift the authentication state above the `Nav` component and pass it as a prop (or consume in context) and set the active link state accordingly. The following solution uses a React Context.

1. Create an `AuthContext` and provider component.

   ```
   const AuthContext = createContext({
     authorized: false,
     profile: null,
     setAuthorized: () => {},
     setProfile: () => {}
   });

   const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
     const [profile, setProfile] = useState();
     const [authorized, setAuthorized] = useState(null);

     const value = {
       authorized,
       profile,
       setAuthorized,
       setProfile
     };

     return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
   };
   ```

Wrap the `Router` with the `AuthProvider`

```
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/shop">
            <Shop />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/my_profile">
            <Profile profile={"currentUser"} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/:profile_name">
            <Profile />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
```

2. Consume the `AuthContext` in `Profile` to set auth state. I.E. swap the old `useState` hooks for the `useContext` hook.

   ```
   function Profile(props) {
     const { profile_name } = useParams();
     const { authorized, profile, setAuthorized, setProfile } = useContext(
       AuthContext
     );

     ...

     return (
       <div>
         Profile:
         <br />
         {profile && <>Name: {profile.name}</>}
         <br />
         {authorized && profile && <>Edit your profile, {profile.name}</>}
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```
3. Consume the `AuthContext` in `Nav` to ready the auth state and set the `NavLink` active state accordingly.

   ```
   function Nav() {
     const { authorized } = useContext(
       AuthContext
     );

     const isActive = {
       fontWeight: "bold",
       backgroundColor: "lightgrey"
     };

     return (
       <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li className="nav-item">
           <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/Shop" activeStyle={isActive}>
             Shop
           </NavLink>
         </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
           <NavLink
             isActive={() => authorized} // <-- pass isActive callback
             className="nav-link"
             to="/my_profile"
             activeStyle={isActive}
           >
             My Profile
           </NavLink>
         </li>
       </ul>
     );
   }
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-set-a-navlink-to-active-on-conditionally-dynamic-links]

[image]

## Edit

> Only I still see a complication. Once we navigate to /dash123 the
> authorized context is set, and My Profile active- as I want-good. But
> if we then click "Shop", Shop becomes active but My Profile is still
> active and it shouldn't be. We could fix this by changing the
> authorized context in the Shop component. It seems this could get out
> of hand because we'd have to access and change the context from every
> component that is linked or redirect coming from Profile. Is there a
> simpler solution or is this just a complication that's to be expected?

Best I could do for this is to simplify the routes a bit by nesting user profile ids under the "/my_profile" path, and applying a bit more logic on the path matching in the `Nav` component.

1. Consolidate the profile routes into a single `Route` that renders for both URLs. Notice here that order of path matching still matters, specifying the more specific path first.

   ```
   <Route path={["/my_profile/:profile_name", "/my_profile"]}>
     <Profile />
   </Route>
   ```
2. Instead of passing a `profile` prop to `Profile`, provide it as a default param value. Update the `useEffect` logic to use `profile_name`.

   ```
   const { profile_name = "currentUser" } = useParams();

   ...

   useEffect(() => {
     if (profile_name === "currentUser") {
       setProfile(currentUser());
     } else {
       setProfile(userInfo(profile_name));
     }
   }, [profile_name, props.profile]);
   ```
3. Use the `useRouteMatch` hook to match the "/my_profile" path prefix and adjust the `isActive` callback logic. The link should be active if an exact match to "/my_profile", ***or*** an in-exact match ***and*** user authenticated.

   ```
   const match = useRouteMatch("/my_profile");

   ...

   <NavLink
     isActive={() => match?.isExact || (match && authorized)}
     className="nav-link"
     to="/my_profile"
     activeStyle={isActive}
   >
     My Profile
   </NavLink>
   ```

[image: Edit how-to-set-a-navlink-to-active-on-conditionally-dynamic-links (forked)]

Comment: Thanks this was one solution I wondered about. Only I still see a complication. Once we navigate to `/dash123` the authorized context is set, and My Profile active- as I want-good. But if we then click "Shop", Shop becomes active but My Profile is still active and it shouldn't be. We could fix this by changing the authorized context in the Shop component. It seems this could get out of hand because we'd have to access and change the context from every component that is linked or redirect coming from Profile. Is there a simpler solution or is this just a complication that's to be expected?

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss Sure, I see that. Looking into it now. Do you have any wiggle room to place the `:profile_name` route param nested in a "/my_profile" route, i.e. like "/my_profile/:profile_name". The main issue is that there isn't a clear way to disambiguate your routes since they are all at the same depth.

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss Took some liberties with the routes but I believe my added edit addresses the additional issue(s) you mention. Please check it out if it sufficiently resolves them.

Comment: Thanks, while I do want the route to be `/:profile_name`, your two solutions gave me an idea. I saved the routes into an array. I used `useRouteMatch` to check that the current route is a non profile route from this array and that authorized is true. Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/active-nav-link--i-think-it-works-ogc5p?file=/src/App.js. I think it works. Since you got me to this answer and if this looks good, if you want to include it in your answer I can then give you Best Answer. Otherwise, I'll post it later myself unless I notice something wrong with it.

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss That is close, but struggles with not highlighting the "profile" routes after navigating to "/my_profile" and then back to "/". Seems the way you've mocked a user profile/authorized makes the "authorized state" a little more "sticky" than it should be. I took your idea a step or two further and defined profile and nonProfile path arrays and additional logic, but then sort of hit the other side of this "authorized" issue with the profile path still highlighting with "bob123". I don't have time ATM to wrangle a mocked auth flow, but can continue in a few hours.

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss The trouble I still foresee is how to differentiate between the profile path "/my_profile" and any auth state, and "/:profile_name" with authorized true state, without going down a rabbit hole of if-else-if-else-if type patterns. I'll need to think about this for a bit.

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating the profile not getting highlighted. But for your point about the auth state, maybe we could have a separate context or a state so that it's more specific. So "My Profile" will only be active when both the route is a profile route AND "currentUsersProfile" was set to true, which will always be reset on Profile and only on Profile. Here I put "currentUsersProfile" on the AuthContext, and it seems to work, though not sure if that's the cleanest place to put "currentUsersProfile" codesandbox.io/s/activenavlink-currentusersprofilecontext-4so4x. What do you think? –

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229707/discussion-between-dashiell-rose-bark-huss-and-drew-reese).